# Directive inside directive. Compile is not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am still rather new to angular JS, and wanted to learn about directives. I want to make a nested directives, kind like menu such as this:

```
<myDirective>Hello</myDirective>
```

Pretty simple, and I've put it like this with $compile:

```
.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<dialog2><div ng-transclude></div></dialog2>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
  };
})
.directive('dialog2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<b>Hi</b><div ng-transclude></div> there'
  };
});
```

Now, it only shows as

```
Hello
```

And it should say

```
Hi Hello there
```

Where did I do wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simple thing to note when declare a directive in html use `my-directive` instead of `myDirective`

```
<my-directive>Hello</my-directive>
```

Also no need to complie in same contents again without modifying DOM.If you any directive/custom directive applied in template or templareUrl angularjs will complie for us before handover to us.

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/bfmtxed7/1/)

Comment: ah.. that simple.. Thank you